# Views Data Export not working as intended

Tags: views

I just installed [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and its working fine. But after updating Drupal core from 7.34 to 7.36 it stops working as intended. **Views** also failed in slideshow module, **libraries** disappeared and impossible to create any views with download format.

Anyone know how to fix this? I need to export sales data from my website.